# Importance of workflow visualization in a statistical software package?

Tags: software, project-management

From a blog [post](http://r4stats.com/2016/02/22/vcf/)

> ... The important thing is why they’re missing. Gartner excluded them this year, “…due to not satisfying the [new] visual composition framework [VCF] inclusion criteria.” VCF is the term they’re using to describe the workflow (also called streams or flowcharts) style of Graphical User Interface (GUI). To be included in the 2016 plot, companies must have offered software that uses the workflow GUI. What Garter is saying is, in essence, advanced analytics software that does not use the workflow interface is not worth following!

...

> While menu-driven interfaces such as R Commander, Deducer or SPSS are somewhat easier to learn, the flowchart interface has two important advantages. First, you can often get a grasp of the big picture as you see steps such as separate files merging into one, or several analyses coming out of a particular data set. Second, and more important, you have a precise record of every step in your analysis. This allows you to repeat an analysis simply by changing the data inputs.

The blogger appears to be arguing that analytical software needs to have VCF (or a GUI interface) for two reasons.  One is "grasp the big picture" and two is that it is self documenting.

I would argue that the "big picture" argument is specious logic as having VCF doesn't guarantee that one grasps all the elements that go into an analytics project.  I would argue that the second point is also incorrect as my R scripts are pretty well self documenting without a GUI-like flowchart.

Still, the Gartner report which is quoted in the blog makes VCF a requirement for consideration, and analytical software has strongly drifted in that direction.

My question is should "VCF" be a strong consideration when deciding on analytical software and if so, what features does it bring that regular programming like software (R scripts) do not?